# Humorous short story about a young woman who wants to demonstrate shape-changing to her boyfriend

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, witches, shape-shifter

She's a witch, and talks about proving it to him by shape-changing into a cat or dog. He doesn't believe it, and is preparing to go swimming. She does whatever preparation is necessary for a shape-change, and apparently only has to state what she wants to change into, but at his suggestion she changes into

> a swimsuit, literally.

I thought it might have been a Fredric Brown story, as he wrote several humorous stories involving shape-changing (e.g., "Abominable", "Bear Possibility", "Too Far"), but it doesn't appear in *From These Ashes*, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: I can't claim to have read or remember accurately everything F. Brown has written, but I have read quite a few of his stories and that description doesn't ring a bell for any of his works (I might be wrong, of course).

Comment: I think this is in one of the Asimov-Cronkin collection of 100 Great Short-Short Science Fiction or Fantasy stories.

Comment: Thanks, @Oldcat! The collection title(s) you suggested put me on the right track, though it wasn't Cronkin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story is "Maid to Measure" by Damon Knight, first published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* Vol. 27 No. 4 October 1964, and reprinted in 1966 Knight's collection *Turning On* as well as in the 1978 *100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories*, edited by Isaac Asimov, Martin Harry Greenberg, and Joseph D Olander.